# Set selectedindex for comboboxcell in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I am trying to set the `selectedindex` for my `datagridviewcomboboxcell` through `cellvaluechanged` event,i.e when i change some value in my datagrid row, this column should get automatically changed. here's the code.

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged

          Try       
                If Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value.ToString <> Nothing Then
                    Me.DataGridView1("unit_code", e.RowIndex).Value = "1" 
                    MsgBox(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(6).Value)
                End If
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```

my datagridview is bound to dataset. Searched many sites and did all research, got the above solution where we need to set the `valuemember` to `.value` part. Even after doing that it gives
`system.formatexception:datagridviewcomboboxcell value is not valid`.

Please help me.

[EDIT]
table structure

`unit_code`    `descp`
0                              -
1                              nos
2                              kgs
3                              gms

[EDIT 2]

```
 query = "select Switch(qty=0,'2',qty<=rcvd_qty,'1',rcvd_qty=0,'2',qty>rcvd_qty,'3') as Status,item_type,catalogue,name,pd.rate,qty,pd.unit_code" _
                & " from pur_det pd,itemhead th where pd.item_code=th.itemcode and order_no=0 order by catalogue"

            adap1 = New OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn)
            Dim saldet As New DataSet
            adap1.Fill(saldet, "puritems")

            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = saldet.Tables(0)
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(0).HeaderText = "STATUS"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(0).Width = 68
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(1).HeaderText = "TYPE"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(1).Width = 60
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(2).HeaderText = "CATALOGUE"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(2).Width = 140
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(3).HeaderText = "DESCRIPTION"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(3).Width = 300
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(4).HeaderText = "RATE"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(4).Width = 60
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(5).HeaderText = "QUANTITY"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(5).Width = 84
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(6).HeaderText = "UNIT" ' this column is removed below because it only had primary key values of this table("unitmast").
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(6).Width = 70

            adap1 = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from unitmast order by unitcode ASC", conn)
            Dim unitc As New DataSet
            adap1.Fill(unitc, "unitmast")

            Me.DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(6) 'here the same is added with display member to view its actual value
            Dim uncol As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
            With uncol
                .Name = "unit_code"
                .DataPropertyName = "unit_code"
                .DataSource = unitc.Tables(0)
                .ValueMember = "unitcode"
                .DisplayMember = "desc"
                .HeaderText = "UNIT"
                .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
                .DropDownWidth = 160
                .Width = 70
            End With
            Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(6, uncol)
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What is the dataset? How do you bind the dataset? Which column is the combobox? How many items the combobox has? Show more code please

Comment: Check my answer, it shows how you can set the value to `nos` directly or set it using its index of the ComboBoxCell items collection.

Comment: Show us the line code you have now, it's working perfectly for me.
If you do this: 
`combo.Value = combo.Items(1)`
It will select the item with `index = 1`

Comment: By the way, fill your `unitc` `DataSet` with the `desc` field only: `SELECT desc FROM unitmast ORDER BY unitcode ASC`

Comment: But at insert time, i need unit_code.@TeaWithCookies

Comment: `Dim combo As DataGridViewComboBoxCell`
combo = CType(Me.DataGridView1("unit_code", e.RowIndex),DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
                        combo.Value = combo.Items(1)

Comment: @TeaWithCookies is there a issue with my `datapropertyname`?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε please help.

Comment: I think it's because you have this: `.ValueMember = "unitcode"`. The first column in your database is `unit_code`, not `unitcode`. Also check my answer again, you need to use the first case, and remove the `DataPropertyName`.

Comment: Nope. change everything in database to `unit_code` still not working.

Comment: I mean on your code! The `.ValueMember` property has to match the name of the first column of your database table, and the `.DisplayMember` matches the second column.

Comment: I believe @TeaWithCookies is right. You need to `CType` the *combobox* and set the `index` to 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` has no `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedValue` property.

You can set the value directly like this:

```
CType(Me.DataGridView1("unit_code", e.RowIndex), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = "your value string"
```

Or using the index of the items collection: (this works only if you have not set `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties)

```
Dim combo As DataGridViewComboBoxCell
combo = CType(Me.DataGridView1("unit_code", e.RowIndex), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
combo.Value = combo.Items('your index')
```

You can also check a value for nothing like this:

```
If Not Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value Is Nothing Then
    'Your code
End If
```

Comment: Nope. Still gives same error. It sets `1` in the combo cell rather than setting its value ie `nos`.

Comment: Are you sure there is a `"1"` value in the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` items collection? Maybe that is why that exception occurs. Remember you are setting the `value`, not the `index`.

Answer (score 2):

I Write and Test that Code For You Good Luck:

```
Dim Dt As New DataTable
Sub CreateDT()
    Dt.Columns.Add("Col1")
    Dt.Columns.Add("Col2")

    Dt.Rows.Add(New Object(1) {"1", "A"})
    Dt.Rows.Add(New Object(1) {"2", "B"})
    Dt.Rows.Add(New Object(1) {"3", "C"})
End Sub
Private Sub ChildRibbonForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CreateDT()
    '
    'Dim CellCol As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = CType(DataGridView1.Columns(0), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)

    Dim CellCol As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    CellCol.Items.Add("Test1")
    CellCol.Items.Add("Test2")
    CellCol.Items.Add("Test3")

    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Dt
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, CellCol)
    Dim CellBox As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = CType(DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(0), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
    'Select the Second Item
    CellBox.Value = CellCol.Items(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: wanted it to change on cellvaluechanged event. Your are loading it on form load.

Comment: Just Call the last part of Code when we change the selected item in CellValueChanged Event.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Declare datatable
Dim cdt as new Datatable
'Add columns with types. It is important you specify the type for value member column
cdt.Columns.Add("vm", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
cdt.Columns.Add("dm", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))

'Add items to table
cdt.Rows.Add
cdt.Rows(0).Item(0) = 1
cdt.Rows(0).Item(1) = "Red Cat"
cdt.Rows.Add
cdt.Rows(1).Item(0) = 2
cdt.Rows(1).Item(1) = "Black Cat"

'Add datasource to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
Dim cc As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
cc = datagridview1.Columns('colIndex')
cc.DataSource = cdt
cc.ValueMember = "vm"
cc.DisplayMember = "dm"

'Setting then selected value is thus:
Datagridview1.Rows('rowIndex').Cells('colIndex').Value = 2  '2 for black cat
```

This works for me

Comment: Is this an answer to the question ,what is Red Cat etc. (They don't seem to be from the question)